# Probability of getting a small straight in 3 or less rolls

Tags: probability

What is the probability of getting a small straight in 3 or less rolls in a [Yahtzee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahtzee) game? How to calculate it?

If you get a large straight it counts as success.

I did an improvised count and got a result of

$P=\frac{154185}{667378}$

Can anyone confirm it?.

Comment: an interesting "practical" :) question -- but the answer depends on your strategy of what to keep, and obviously the real question is what is the probability assuming optimal strategy.  how did you calculate $P$, i.e. what strategy did you assume (and why do you think it's optimal)?

Comment: I did the calculation with a program. But now, with your question, I realized that I'm not sure if my strategy is optimal (I'll bet it's not). In fact, it doesn't seem so simple to choose what to keep in each roll. For example: if the first roll yields 11455:
Is keep 14 a better choice than keep 45? Or is it better to keep 145?
Obviously the 4 should be kept because it is part of all the possible stairs (like the 3)....What happens if we get in the first roll 11166?